# sas count changes between date and variable grouped by id

Tags: sas

I'm trying to get the count of changes in default variable based on ID and Date. I'm a week old into using SAS so please forgive me if I need detailed explanations.

I currently have

```
data test111;
input Date $ Acc $ Default $;
datalines;
jan-10 A N
feb-10 A D
mar-10 A D
apr-10 A D
may-10 A D
jan-10 B N
feb-10 B N
mar-10 B D
apr-10 B D
may-10 B D
jan-10 C N
feb-10 C N
mar-10 C N
apr-10 C D
may-10 C D
jan-10 D N
feb-10 D D
mar-10 D N
apr-10 D D
may-10 D D
jan-10 E D
feb-10 E D
mar-10 E D
apr-10 E N
may-10 E D
```

I want an output (Table 1 below) that counts when default changes from **N to D** for each unique accounts. But it is dependent on Date. I only know how to use Excel to show the output desired (manually counting). Table 2 is how the accounts are counted if I'm not clear.

```
Table 1
    month+1 month+2 month+3 month+4
Jan-10  2   1   1   0
Feb-10  1   1   0   
Mar-10  2   0       
Apr-10  1           

Table 2 (FYR)               
    month+1 month+2 month+3 month+4
Jan-10  A,D B   C   -
Feb-10  B   C   -   
Mar-10  C,D -       
Apr-10  E
```

I've tried something like creating a new column that tags when N changes to D so I can sum when tag =1

```
by first.Acc
if first.Acc then tag = 0;
if default = 'D' then do;
tag = 1;
tag+1;
```

Not sure if this will get me the correct result for my first line.
But if this works it can only give me the first row of my desired output. I have over 100 months and is it possible to loop or array it?

In case my SAS data input skills fail I've included the Excel screenshot.
[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47yBC.png)

Comment: Are the values like 'Apr-10' supposed to represents months?  If you want them to sort properly you will need to them as actual dates.  What are you counting?

Comment: I think your initial attempt will only give you the first *column* of your intended output, not the first *row*.

Comment: @Tom yes those are dates. the goal is to count the number of accounts that jumps from N to D based on dates. if at jan 2010 it's N and feb 2010 it's D, month+1 will be count 1. if at jan 2010 it's N and apr 2010 it's D, month+3 will be count 1. and the count keeps moving when i start N at different months to yield Table 1

Comment: @user667489 you're right. it was just an idea on how to create another table to count instances of N to D. but i can't take into consideration of the moving of dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most general solution will involve a full outer join within each group.

SQL can perform the join and compute the months apart for the case of a month with N default to the next earliest month with D default.  Tabulate can present a grid of the counts.

**Data**

The month strings are converted to SAS 1-st of month date values that are formatted `yymon` for display purposes.

```
data have;
input Date $ Acc $ Default $;
month = input ('01-'||date, date9.);
format month yymon.;
datalines;
jan-10 A N
feb-10 A D
mar-10 A D
apr-10 A D
may-10 A D
jan-10 B N
feb-10 B N
mar-10 B D
apr-10 B D
may-10 B D
jan-10 C N
feb-10 C N
mar-10 C N
apr-10 C D
may-10 C D
jan-10 D N
feb-10 D D
mar-10 D N
apr-10 D D
may-10 D D
jan-10 E D
feb-10 E D
mar-10 E D
apr-10 E N
may-10 E D
run;
```

**Sample SQL**

```
proc sql;
  create view have_v as
  select 
    left.acc
  , left.month as from_month
  , right.month as to_month
  , intck ('MONTH', left.month, right.month) as months_apart
  from 
    have as left
    join have as right on left.acc = right.acc
    where 
      left.month < right.month
    & left.default = 'N'
    & right.default = 'D'
  group by left.acc, left.month
  having right.month = min(right.month)
  order by
    left.month, right.month
  ;

  create table grid_bounds as
  select 
    min(from_month) as min_from
  , max(from_month) as max_from
  , 1 as min_apart
  , max(months_apart) as max_apart
  from have_v
  ;
```

**SQL Explained**

A self join is a join of a table against itself.

```
have as left join have as right
```

The join constraint restricts the `from/to` month combinations to be only those in the same account

```
on left.acc = right.acc
```

The where constraint further restricts the `from/to` combinations to be only those with `to` in the future and having the desired `default` transition

```
where 
  left.month < right.month
& left.default = 'N'
& right.default = 'D'
```

The `group by` operator and SAS `Proc SQL` `having` clause automatic remerge feature allows a simple statement for selecting the earliest `to` for a given `from`

```
group by left.acc, left.month
having right.month = min(right.month)
```

For the selected rows of the join the months apart can be computed using SAS data function `INTCK` (I think of the function name as an acronym for the phrase "INTerval Count of a period Kind")

```
, intck ('MONTH', left.month, right.month) as months_apart
```

A specific solution could use array if the largest group size is known apriori.

**Tabulate for output**

Some months may not be present due to no transitions. Likewise, some gaps may also not be present.  These cases will not have any rows in `have_v`.  In order to get a *full coverage* for the report, all possible crossings (or combinations) are generated for use in `Proc TABULATE`

```
proc sql;
  create table grid_bounds as
  select 
    min(from_month) as min_from
  , max(from_month) as max_from
  , 1 as min_apart
  , max(months_apart) as max_apart
  from have_v
  ;
quit;

data grid (label="All crossings to be shown in the output");
  set grid_bounds;
  do from_month = min_from to max_from;
    do months_apart = 1 to max(12,max_apart);
      OUTPUT;
    end;
  end;
  keep from_month months_apart;
  format from_month yymon.;
run;
```

Outputs a grid report with gap frequencies for each from_month

```
options missing = '0' nocenter;

title "Account frequency";
title2 "Gap of month default changing from N to D";

proc tabulate data=have_v classdata=grid;
  class from_month months_apart;

  table 
    from_month=''
    , months_apart * N=''
  ;
run;

options missing = '.';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the script & explanation. But I'm having trouble running it on my dataset.

My grid bounds table yields 1 row of results with 4 columns.
My grid table yields 1 column of result with over 200,000 rows.

Log error says
    1. class variable from_month not found in preload data set/incompatible with primary data set variable of the same name
    2.  variable from_month is not on file work.grid

Comment: Oh I forgot. My existing dataset date format is in mmddyy10. I tried formatting it to yymon. but i don't see the changes in my table have.

`data have;`
`set work.temp1`
`month = input(month, MMDDYY10.);`
`format month yymon.;`
`run;`

could this be causing the issue?

Comment: `mmddyy10.` is more detail than the data in the question.  If your data is actually at that level, and you want output to present rows at the day level, you will want to also format `month` as `MMDDYY10.`  You may want to change variable name `month` to a name that better describes the data in the problem.  Post additional questions as a new question -- restrict it to just the 'formatting issue' you are experiencing.  Show sample input and output if possible.

Comment: Thanks. Ok got it. With regards to the sample sql you wrote, as of now have table only shows the first instance N changes to D. If i have certain accounts that goes like this N -> D -> N -> N -> D, I want to count the 5th D as well.
I noticed that default will only change status to D if the previous month status has been N, so I can disregard the condition of `left.default = 'C'`. But I still can't get the correct count.

Comment: The `group by/having` part of the SQL restricts the selection to the first 'to' month with default D.  Remove the `group by left.acc, left.month
having right.month = min(right.month)` part of the SQL.  The result set will include all 'to' months that have a default D

Comment: The code works great. Thank you so much. You're a life saver!